# Suppressing Python warnings with PYTHONWARNINGS

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I'd like to suppress some warnings about `python setup.py install` being deprecated [1], and have managed to do this on Debian Buster and Bookworm with the `PYTHONWARNINGS` facility, in my Makefile

```
PYWARN1 := ignore:::setuptools.command.install
PYWARN2 := ignore:::setuptools.command.easy_install
export PYTHONWARNINGS = $(PYWARN1),$(PYWARN2)
```

and all is quiet.  But this doesn't work on Debian Trixie (testing).  Looking at the sources (used in creating the corresponding Debian package) the difference seems to be, in the file `setuptools/command/install.py`

Bookworm: `setuptools-66.1.1`

```py
    def initialize_options(self):
        warnings.warn(
            "setup.py install is deprecated. "
            "Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.",
            setuptools.SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
        )
```

Trixie: `setuptools-68.1.2`

```py
    def initialize_options(self):
        SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning.emit(
            "setup.py install is deprecated.",
            """
            Please avoid running ``setup.py`` directly.
            Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
            standards-based tools.
            """,
            see_url="https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html",
```

I tried adding an `ignore:::SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning`, and `ignore:::setuptools.SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning`, no joy.  Anyone have any ideas?

[1] I am blocked from actually switching to pip since `pip3 install --prefix` is currently [broken](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1035546) on Debian.